# JavaFX TableView with observablelist: How to keep rows selected?

Tags: javafx, tableview, selection

I am using a JavaFX TableView to show data stored in an observablelist. The SelectionMode of the TableView is set to multiple. I want the user to be able to select multiple rows while the data in the list is updated.

My problem is that the selection is reset as soon as data in the observable list is changed and only one row remains selected. The number of items in the list is not changed - so I do not add or delete items to/from the list, just their status is changed.

Is there a way to keep the multiple row selection even when the observeable list is changed?

I could probably read out the current selection before the change occures and try to restore the selection in code. But the list is updated very frequently and this does not seem very effective. I hope there is a better solution.

P.S.: Changes to the observablelist occure inside of a JavaFX-Thread.

Here is a minimal example showing my problem (select several rows and press the update button - only last row will still be selected):

```
package javafxtableviewtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JavaFXTableViewTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }   
}
```

Controller:

```
package javafxtableviewtest;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;


public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    List<SomeData> dataList = new ArrayList();
    private ObservableList<SomeData> observedList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataList); 

    @FXML
    private Button updatButton;
    @FXML
    private TableView myTable;       

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            SomeData newData = new SomeData();
            newData.setID(i);
            newData.setStatus(0);
            observedList.add(newData);
        }
        myTable.setItems(observedList);
        myTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    }    

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Update table!");
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Integer index = 5;
                SomeData newData = new SomeData();
                newData.setID(index);
                newData.setStatus(observedList.get(index).getStatus() + 1);
                observedList.set(index, newData);
            }
        });        
    }
}
```

Model:

```
package javafxtableviewtest;

public class SomeData {
    private int ID;
    private int status;

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

}
```

FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="684.0" prefWidth="827.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="javafxtableviewtest.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="694.0" layoutY="616.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" text="Update" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <TableView fx:id="myTable" layoutX="42.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="562.0" prefWidth="707.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="20.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="ID">
              <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="ID" />
              </cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
          <TableColumn editable="false" maxWidth="100.0" minWidth="20.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Status">
              <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="status" />
              </cellValueFactory>
          </TableColumn>
        </columns>
      </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: sounds like a bug to me .. could you please provide an example demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Ok, I have added a minimal code example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: thanks ... yeah, can reproduce with java9-ea-u180 - indeed a bug. You might consider filing an issue in the openjdk bug repo

Comment: okay, filed an issue myself (really thought all rough edges around data modification and selection had been fixed, naive me ;) https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8186908 BTW: you don't need the runlater in your eventHandler, they are always on the FX-thread :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for filing this issue. I think I also found a way around it using StringProperties etc. Will probably post here when I am sure it's working. Then I don't have to replace an item in the list, I just change the item.